# localStorage/options page in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension in JavaScript for a College project. It's an automated checkout system for a specific website. I have a background.js which uses a nested `chrome.tabs.executeScript` function to execute three locally stored .js scripts in a sequence. The third script is an 'autofill' script which fills in the user's information (defined in the the .js file itself). I'd like to create an options page where the user can input their shipping address, save, then run the extension and the latter inputted values are assigned to the address fields on the webpage. I, however, have no idea where to even start with this idea, as so far the autofill values like the name and address have been set in my script code! I've tried to understand the little information I've discovered on this subject but I'm lost as to how to apply it to my situation. Here are my script files:

Background.html

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "part 1.js" }, function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "part 2.js" }, function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "part 3.js" }, function() {
})
})
})
});
```

Part 3.js

```
document.getElementById('order_billing_name').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_email').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_tel').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_billing_address').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_billing_address_2').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_billing_city').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_billing_zip').value="foo";
document.getElementById('order_billing_country').value="GB";
```

This is purely a thrown together project entirely based on functionality. As long as it runs and does what it's supposed to do, there's to be no focus on tidiness of code, good practices or the practicality of a function or script. (Not yet anyway!). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Please try and keep it as basic as possible in terms of terminology as I'm very inexperienced. Thanks!

Comment: You can edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646785/using-strings-in-javascript-between-a-html-and-js-file instead of asking a completely new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome, you can install the TamperMonkey extension.
This will let you make local scripts for specific pages.

[Tamper Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

With it, you can change elements on a page and insert a button to to run your script on the page.

I'd also advise using jQuery, as its more powerful and user-friendly when making changes to a website. You can also use the Chrome developer tools to test and make changes on the fly.